# Have images in 3 wrapper divs but need to view only one div at a time. too slow loading

Tags: html, image

I have 3 sets of images in 3 separate divs that are hard coded into the webpage. Only one set is viewed at a time by user choice button. This was ok when there were only 5 images in each set but now that I added more, the page is loading so slowly. The pictures are 1200 by 900 px because I am using nivo-slider which allows sizing.
Is there a way to load only the picture set that is clicked?

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default" id="wrapper1" >
    <div class="nivoSlider" id="c1" >
         <img src="images/Germany2008/GermanyTrip01.jpg" alt="" />
         <img src="images/Germany2008/GermanyTrip02.jpg" alt="" />
          <!--etc. -->                                         
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default" id="wrapper2" > 
    <div class="nivoSlider" id="c2">
         <img src="images/Germany2008/GermanyTrip01.jpg" alt="" />
         <img src="images/Germany2008/GermanyTrip02.jpg" alt="" />
          <!--etc. -->           
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can add each group of images using JavaScript/jQuery, and only when a group is clicked. You could even choose to load the first group first, and after that start pre-loading the other image.

Comment: @Golez Trol -  That sound like a good way. I do have java script written for the 3 buttons that the user clicks to choose which slider. Could you kind of direct me as to how to write up the jquery or java script to add to a div onclick? sorry I am a beginner that has taken on a project for our choir. I think that I have done well with a lot of help from Stack Overflow, in getting 3 slide shows going :)  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @leppie - I don't understand why your avatar is next to my post. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not perfectly clear on what you want but I'll try.

Add the following javascript at the bottom of the body:

```
var wrapperOneImages = ["path/to/image","path/to/image","path/to/image"];
var wrapperTwoImages = ["path/to/image","path/to/image","path/to/image"];
var amountOfWrappers = 2;
for (i=0; i < amountOfWrappers; i++) {
    var nivoSlider = document.createElement("div");
    nivoSlider.setAttribute("class", "nivoSlider");
    nivoSlider.setAttribute("id", "c" + toString(i+1));
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper" + toString(i+1));
    if (i == 0) {
        var whatWrapper = wrapperOneImages;
    } else if (i == 1) {
        var whatWrapper = wrapperTwoImages;
    }
    for (j=0; j < whatWrapper.length; j++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var img.setAttribute("src", whatWrapper[j]);
        nivoSlider.appendChild(img);
    }
    wrapper.appendChild(nivoSlider);
}
```

And replace all of the html you provided with the following:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default" id="wrapper1" ></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default" id="wrapper2" ></div>
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thank you. I really appreciate your time.  I have also been scouring the past posts trying to understand some of the ways people have done this.

Comment: Ok. I haven't tested it myself but I'm pretty sure it'll work